# Customer not able to login and place order

Tags: magento2, customer-account, customer-session

I was looking for solution to my problem.

We are using Magento 2.2.3 version and one of our customer facing problem when he logged in, His not able to purchase due session destroying every time he refresh page or going on next page.

As I found error **{"message":"No such entity with customerId = "}** in browser console on url

**`https://myshop.com/customer/section/load/?sections=&update_section_id=false&_=1545041906558`**

I try to edit customer information from admin panel where ever time I got error about State/Province. **"State/Province" length must be equal or less than 20 characters."**

We are facing this issue for only 1 customer, there is no problem with other customer.

Some notes on customer.

1. This customer has 11 addresses in address book.
2. This customer was able to place order suddenly facing this issue now.

Any hints, guidelines are appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It looks like his session is missing customer id. Using incognito mode or another browser should resolve the issue. If so then clearing cookies and local storage should resolve the issue in his or hers main browser.

This situation can also happen if you have subdomain which produces session cookie with the same key and the two got mixed up.

Comment: your 2nd point may be true, Is there any suggestion to solve this?
I tried all options mentioned in 1st point but no success.
Thanks

Comment: Not much, as cookie with domain `it.domain.com` will always be sent to `domain.com`. The best thing you can do is use `www.domain.com` as a base instead of `domain.com`, and keep `it.domain.com` (or whatever you have them for). That way all domains will be separated.